# Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a subview of UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, subview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Im having problems receiving a `UITapGesture` on a `UILabel` which is a subview of a `UIPickerView`.

```
let statusDisplayLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                               y: 0,
                                           width: <#width of UIPickerView #>,
                                          height: <# height of UIPickerView row #>))

statusDisplayLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                        action: #selector(didTapStatusDisplayLabel(tap:)))

tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
statusDisplayLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)



<# UIPickerView #>.addSubview(statusDisplayLabel)



@objc func didTapStatusDisplayLabel(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer){
                print("tapped")
}
```

The `UILabel` displays as it should over the `UIPickerView`. However "tapped" message is never displayed in console as the tap just falls through the `statusDisplayLabel` and moves the `UIPickerView` instead. It's as if the `UILabel` is not there

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create *Container View*, put into this view your UIPickerView and try to add label not into the picker view, but inside the Container View.

Comment: Who have though but adding the Label to the container view and not the uipickerview worked. Many thanks

Comment: The pickerview was added in Storyboard so I just added the Label as Subview of the base UIView

Answer (score 1):

Check following

First check view hierarchy, is label on top of picker view

if all correct then

Here, missing  part is only `userInteractionEnabled`

**EDIT**

You can debug view hierarchy using

[image]

**EDIT2**

You can implement `func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?` in subclass of `UIView`  as alternative solution. If you need demo then I can post

Comment: I set enabled and no change. I assume the Label is on top as thats how it is displayed. it blocks out the uipickerview. Is there a way to check this in code?